# Fatal exception:main Android Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, exception, runtime

I am new on android and trying to develop simple calculator but this Fatal exception : main occurs please help.

I did comment my onClickListner to check but it did'nt helped at all.

```
package com.example.calculatorsinglescreen;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText value1,value2,myoperator,result;
Button ok;
String strvalue1,strvalue2,stroperator,strresult;
int ivalue1,ivalue2,ioperator,iresult;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    value1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtvalue1);
    value2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtvalue2);
    myoperator = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtoperator);
    result = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtresult);
    ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnok);

    strvalue1 = value1.getText().toString();
    strvalue2 = value2.getText().toString();
    stroperator = myoperator.getText().toString();

    ivalue1 = Integer.parseInt(strvalue1);
    ivalue2 = Integer.parseInt(strvalue2);





    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if (stroperator.equals("+")) {

                Toast msg = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "If is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                msg.show();

                }

        }
    });
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

This is my XML file :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.calculatorsinglescreen.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/value1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:text="Value 1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/value2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/value1"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:text="Value 2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/operator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/value2"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:text="Operator" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtvalue1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/value1"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/value1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtoperator"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/operator"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtvalue2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/operator"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:ems="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtvalue2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/value2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/value2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtvalue1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:ems="10" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnok"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Ok" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnok"
    android:layout_margin="40dp"
    android:text="Result" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtresult"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/result"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/result"
    android:ems="10" />
```

Here is my LogCat to get a clearer view :

```
10-18 17:51:25.468: D/AndroidRuntime(742): Shutting down VM
10-18 17:51:25.468: W/dalvikvm(742): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
10-18 17:51:25.488: E/AndroidRuntime(742): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-18 17:51:25.488: E/AndroidRuntime(742): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.calculatorsinglescreen/com.example.calculatorsinglescreen.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
10-18 17:51:25.488: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
10-18 17:51:25.488: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
10-18 17:51:25.488: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-18 17:51:25.488: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
10-18 17:51:25.488: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-18 17:51:25.488: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-18 17:51:25.488: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-18 17:51:25.488: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-18 17:51:25.488: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-18 17:51:25.488: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-18 17:51:25.488: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-18 17:51:25.488: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-18 17:51:25.488: E/AndroidRuntime(742): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
10-18 17:51:25.488: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:362)
10-18 17:51:25.488: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
10-18 17:51:25.488: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at com.example.calculatorsinglescreen.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
10-18 17:51:25.488: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-18 17:51:25.488: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
10-18 17:51:25.488: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Stacktrace (logcat) please...

Comment: What is the value of ioperator?

Comment: @jyoon LogCat is added

Comment: There. `java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer` on line 3.

Comment: @jyoon can you provide solution what to do?

Comment: `operator` is a keyword used by Java and should not be used. Change it to myOperator or something else.

Comment: Did that but still the same!

Comment: You're trying to get an integer from +, where there is no integer!

Comment: But I already deleted that line

Comment: Please paste your entire code. Nobody is going to steal your *code*.

Comment: There is nothing to steal :) and I've pasted all code with XML

Comment: and upvote will be really welcomed you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
```

check your line 24 and see if you cast the right widget in java -(xml), this error means incompatible cast widget lol...

if everything seems correct-(mean widgets are cast in java to with their respective class) then clean rebuild and restart..

EDIT: It worked.. you've solved it but there is a new error which is

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException:
```

its because of this on these lines

```
ivalue1 = Integer.parseInt(strvalue1);
ivalue2 = Integer.parseInt(strvalue2);
ioperator = Integer.parseInt(stroperator);
```

so change these to this

```
Integer.valueOf(strvalue1); do that as follows
```

and also looking at your codes.. your string values are pullled from the edittext during oncreate which means when the app starts in oncreate before the Onresume(which is called when the app shows on the), and during oncreate the user cant flirt with your app, and going further to input values, so at the end your strings are empty when you pull from the edittext, so basically what im saying is remove these lines

```
strvalue1 = value1.getText().toString();
```

and put them in the click events ... i am lucid enough to you??..

EDIT2: OVERALL CODE
   for button click

```
ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
         strvalue1 = value1.getText().toString();
         strvalue2 = value2.getText().toString();
         stroperator = myoperator.getText().toString();

         ivalue1 =  Integer.valueOf(strvalue1);
         ivalue2 =  Integer.valueOf(strvalue2);

        if (stroperator.equals("+")) {

           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "If is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah just got confused by my naming conventions and correct it but still Fatal exception !

Comment: clean rebuild and restart..@HelpingDesk and let us know if it crashes with the same error

Comment: Did'nt worked LogCat is updated now please check again @Elltz

Comment: Mean I should paste my Button listener code in OnResume? Or i should paste my string lines in OnClick method?

Comment: no!! meaning you should paste your value1.getText().toString() and the rest, in your button click listener.. @HelpingDesk

Comment: lol.. i actually edited my answer so you could copy paste it.. am glad you did it on your own.. happy codding@HelpingDesk

Answer (score 0):

remove `ioperator = Integer.parseInt(stroperator);` from the code.I think Your trying to convert the operator to Integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
ioperator = Integer.parseInt(stroperator);
```

if you mean operator like this +,-,/,*  , you only can convert to thr char or stay in string and do something like this:

```
private int plus(int ivalue1 , int ivalue2 , String operator ){
    if(operator.equal("+")){
        return ivalue1 + ivalue2;
    }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Problem is activity not even starting

Comment: ok , give as more code. All Activity , you can hide if you want something important or change name of class...